# Reference class member variables give an error "uninitialized reference" in constructor

Tags: c++, class, pass-by-reference

I have the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vec{
    private:
        int& var;
    public:
        Vec(int& tmp){
            var = tmp;
        }
};
int main(){
    int x = 10;
    Vec v1(x);
}
```

but it gives a compilation error:`error: uninitialized reference member in ‘int&’ [-fpermissive]`

How to resolve this?

Comment: You cannot initialize a reference variable of your class without an initializer list.

Answer (score 5):

You should use an initializer list.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vec{
    private:
        int& var;
    public:
        Vec(int& tmp) : var(tmp) {}
};
int main(){
    int x = 10;
    Vec v1(x);
}
```

Comment: i am not sure what an initializer list means! can someone explain this or point to some good resource? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AJ: Do you know the difference between initialization and assignment?